# C : Increase Dynamic Array by one in a loop

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, realloc

I would like to know why I can't reach to increase my array size by only one in a while loop.
Here is my code :

```
void pb_memory(void){
    printf("ERROR : memory problem !\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
             int length = 0;
            /*allocate memory and check for no error*/
            int *array = calloc(1, sizeof(int)); /*initialize to 0*/
            if(array == NULL)
                     pb_memory();

            /*Check for valid inputs and put into array*/
            while((scanf("%d", &num)) != EOF){
                               array[length]=num;
                               length++;
                               array = realloc(array, length*sizeof(int));
                               if(array == NULL)
                                        pb_memory();
            }
.
.
.
.

}
```

Why is this not working ? It fails and goes directly into the pb_memory() function .I would like every time length increase by one my array does too...

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : Sorry guys I wanted to keep the code simple and focused on my problem that's why I didn't write all my variables. Anyway I'm learning for next time and thanks @Michael and everyone who participate.

Comment: How do you know the initial allocation succeeds? And why `int *(array)` and not `int *array`?

Comment: Try declaring and initializing `length`.

Comment: Post the real code (since this won't compile)

Comment: I declared length = 0; in my code forgot to write it back and *(array) or *array is not the problem I think

Comment: Try declaring `num` also (see post above about posting real code)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we can't solve code that we can't see

Comment: @KevinDTimm what do you mean by real code ?

Comment: @Dovakin940, he means like this http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access to a bad index `array[length]=num;`, if the size of array is `length`, you can't access to `length`-th element.

You have to move the write after the reallocation :

```
/*Check for valid inputs and put into array*/
while((scanf("%d", &num)) != EOF){
  length++;
  array = realloc(array, length*sizeof(int));
  if(array == NULL)
    pb_memory();
  array[length-1]=num;
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily a bad answer, but how did you fathom that from the bad code sample in the OP?

Comment: That was pretty obvious. `length` should be the length of something (ie the array).

Comment: @Michael, nothing is obvious. Assumption is the mother of all "features".

Answer (score -1):

Just some thoughts:
1. include some print statements to see exactly where the code fails
2. run gdb with the output the program. For example, in a CLI, run the command "gdb ./a.out"
3. Where is the variable "num" declared ? It suddenly appears in the while-loop's condition ?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: To comment, I need 50pts reputation minimum, which I don't have.
So I can't comment ... but I can answer